# Anyone can help why in Console or Winform this will get user directory, but I use it in service program been changed to c:/Windows/System32

Tags: windows, service

I am coding a service program and try to get user directory with
var dir = new DirectoryInfo(Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile));

But when I debug it and find out it is in c:/Windows/System32/...
[image]
Can anyone help on this?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What do you think of as the "user directory"?

- Is it the home directory of the user who installed the service?
- Is it the home directory of whatever user happens to be currently logged in?
- Is it the home directory of the last user who was logged in?

No need to answer any of these questions, they are rhetorical.

The point is, the concept of a user does not apply in a windows service. We write windows services precisely because we want to have code running on a machine irrespective of users. A windows service is running while ***any user*** is logged in, and it is also running while ***no user*** is logged in.

For this reason, services run under the "System" account. And as you have already discovered, the "System" account's user profile directory is in `C:/Windows/System32/...`.

So, it is working exactly as designed.

In order to move forward with your problem, you are going to need to revise exactly what it is that you want to accomplish, and perhaps post another stackoverflow question asking how to accomplish it.